# Let $\vec F(x,y)=(y+xg(x),y^2), \vec F(1,1)=(3,1)$. $\vec F_x \perp \vec F_y$.Find $g$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Let $\vec F(x,y)=(y+xg(x),y^2), \vec F(1,1)=(3,1)$. $\vec F_x \perp \vec F_y$
>
> Find $g$.

**Attempt:**

I look for the partial derivatives, I did so differentiating each coordinate with respect to $x$ and $y$ (is this the correct method?).

$F_x=(g+xg',0)$

$ F_y=(1,2y)$

I take the dot product and set it to $0$:

$$g+xg'=0 \implies \dfrac {g'}g=-1/x \implies \ln|g|=-\ln|x|+c \implies |g|=\left|\dfrac {e^c}x \right|$$

Then $F(1,1)=(3,1) \implies g(1)=2$ so$ |g|=\left | \dfrac 2 x \right| $.

How do I take out the absolute value bars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression $|g(x)|=|2/x|\implies g(x)=\pm 2/x$.

But, we also have the condition that $g(1)=2>0$.

Thus,

$$g(x)=\frac{2}{x}$$